# Lost the Admin Password - implementation

Tags: password

I have lost the admin password. Tried the procedure in the detailed thread [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)
but I keep having the same answer. After entering the new UNIX password and retyping it is saying "Authentication token manipulation error" and then "password unchanged"
What should I do?
thanks

Comment: Did you maybe miss the `mount -rw -o remount /` step?

Answer (score 0):

## I DO NOT TAKE CREDIT FOR THIS ANSWER

### From https://askubuntu.com/a/84697/448562:

If [Jorge's method](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/156684) didn't work for you, as it didn't for me, here is another method. I had to try something different because:

1. My USB keyboard did not work at the root prompt ⋯ probably hardware either keyboard or mainboard. To fix I used an old PS/2 keyboard (the little round plug) and use that.
2. When I used `passwd username` to change my password, it failed because of a bad token or such. This called for drastic measures.

### The Drastic Measures

**This is a very dangerous thing to do!** [Jorge's method](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/156684) should be used; *only* do this in case that method doesn't work.

**Do this at your own risk**. It did work for me on my 11.10 system.

The idea is to set the user's password to blank (or null) - this allows you to just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the `Password:` prompt.

Still at the root prompt from [Jorge's method](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/156684), first remount the root file system as read-write by using this command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

- Now you are a super-user on this system. *Tread lightly.*

Then edit the password shadow file to remove the encrypted password for your username. Type in:

```
nano -B /etc/shadow
```

The nano editor will display the contents of the file. Each line will have the form `name:⋯:⋯:⋯…` where ⋯ is a string or null (empty). One of the lines will start with your username. The first ⋯ after your username is your encrypted password. As an example:

```
username:$1$amFeNcjp$PprjCKEVk3UtzKwWfEMOY0:14920:0:99999:7:::
```

where `$1$amFeNcjp$PprjCKEVk3UtzKwWfEMOY0` is the encrypted password.

Carefully delete the encrypted password leaving the all the ":"s, so it looks like this:

```
username::14920:0:99999:7:::
```

Then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to save, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close **nano**.

Reboot and you will have an empty (or null) password.  Be sure to use `passwd username` in a terminal to set  or reset your user password.

Source for PS/2 workaround was [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector).

Sources for the drastic measures were [here](http://www.debuntu.org/recover-root-password-single-user-mode-and-grub) and [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-i-change-the-filesystem-from-read-only-to-read-write-185821/).

Note on nano ― the `-B` option makes a backup of the original edited file, same name with a "~" appended.

Comment: it did not work but I found out that if i run the GRUB first from the main Menu I can get read-write privileges

Comment: thanks to everyone. i will now try to install skype. I guess I will ask again fo rhelp